Does this set agree with these conditions and why? Also, would the set be a dedekind cut?
Would the set $A = \{x ∈ \mathbb{Q}|1 ≤ x < π\}$ satisfies the conditions

$\sup A$ exists and is not in A, and

$\inf A$ exists and lies in A?


Also how could I justify that the supremum and infimum exists, I do not really know how I would go about stating this? Lastly out of curiosity, is this set a Dedekind cut, I'm trying to learn about them but I am not sure what makes something a Dedekind cut.

Definitions of Dedekind cuts vary, but the fact that 1/2 isn't in your set probably makes the answer "no'.

I have attempted to "Latexify" a little your question. Please have a look at the modifications I have brought (for example use of dollar signs around formulas) in order to be able to use some of them next time.

I'll deal with the easiest one first. Yes, $\inf A$ exists and has value 1. Whether your "underlying" set is $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, $1$ is the infimum, since for all $a \in A$, $1 \le a$ and for $y$, whether $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, if for each $a \in A,$ $y\le a$, then $y\le 1$. Thus, $y$ is the greatest lower bound of $A$.
For the supremum, things are more complicated. If your underlying set is $\mathbb{Q}$, then the supremum does not exist -- there is not a single $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is as big as each member of $A$ but is the least such number. (If the sup existed, it would have to be the largest rational smaller than or equal to $\pi$, which of course does not exist.)  On the other hand, if your underlying set is $\mathbb{R}$, then the supremum is just $\pi$ itself.  Whether you can just state these fact or need to prove them depends very much on the assumptions about $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ you are making.
Since you used the notation $A = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}:...\}$, this seems to imply that your $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$, so that the sup does not exist in $X$.
Now to Dedekind cuts:
Typically, given a total ordered set $X$, we say that $A\subseteq X$ is a Dedekind cut of $X$ if:

$A$ is non empty, but is also not all of $X$. (thus, $A$ is not "degenerate," in the sense that it is not $\emptyset$ or $X$.)
for each $a \in A$, if $x \in X$ and $x < a$, then $x \in A$ (you might call this "downwardly closed.")
if $a \in A$, there exists $ b \in A$ so that $a < b$ ($A$ does not contain a maximal element)

[Note that this definition says "is a cut of $X$." You should always specify which set is being "cut" in two. In fact, this points out how a cut works -- we are cutting $X$ into two mutually exclusive parts, $A$ and the complement of $A$. $A$ has the properties listed above -- the complement of $A$ ]
Your set is also not a cut of $\mathbb{Q}$ since its is not downwardly closed. But $B = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}| x < \pi\}$ is a cut -- assuming you have the machinery to define what $\pi$ is. Your set is also not a cut of $\mathbb{R}$ since it is both not downwardly closed -- not just below 1, but also for any irrational below $\pi$.
Often, cuts of $\mathbb{Q}$ are used to define the real numbers. We can in fact say that each real number is just a cut of $\mathbb{Q}$ and then define addition, multiplication, etc on cuts using only those operations in $\mathbb{Q}$.  If you have not seen it, it is a beautiful development, I think!
But you have to watch for circularity if you assume $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$ or something exists to define the cut which is the literal definition of that thing itself.

Note that it is customary to define $\mathbb{R}$ as an ordered field with the least-upper bound property, which furnishes sup/infs for any bounded set. (In fact this makes it the terminal object in the category of ordered fields, hence unique up to unique isomorphism.) Dedekind cuts, Cauchy sequences, etc. are merely implementations, none of which is canonical.
